# Disable accidental dialing of short code numbers

Tags: phone-app, emergency-calls

I live in Europe and use Android v.10 on a Xiaomi Redmi 9A phone.
How to disable accidental dialing of short code numbers (that typically consist of 4-5 digits)?

Comment: Is this question about those numbers usually start with a `#` that allows to execute special functions (like showing IMEI) on your phone?

Comment: @Robert possibly not that one, but [regular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_code) that may accidentally subscribe to carrier's add-ons.

Comment: @AndrewT. So those short codes belong to premium services which means you can accidentally call them and then have to pay a few Euro, Dollar, .. If this is true the real question is how to stop paying for those "hustle numbers" (as I would call them).